# Allow searching for employers that do not put mandatory arbitration agreements into their contracts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Yesterday, the U.S. Supreme Court [dealt a massive blow to workers' rights](http://www.chicagotribune.com/business/ct-biz-supreme-court-arbitration-workers-20180521-story.html), affirming employers' rights to enforce mandatory arbitration agreements in employment contracts. This means that if workers who are in such a contract disagree with some aspect of their employment, they have to do so in private arbitration rather than in court, and workers can't band together to protest potential wrongdoings by employers.

I propose a new feature for Stack Overflow Jobs, which allows employers to identify themselves as not including arbitration agreements in their contracts, so that users searching for jobs can filter out those that do require such agreements.

Comment: I'd be willing to support this feature, but I don't know if the jobs markets are generally so vibrant that workers can afford to turn work down just because this clause would be in their contract.

Comment: @halfer The goal is, more prospective workers would use this option when searching for jobs, and it eventually becomes clear that companies would have to eliminate these clauses to get good workers (because they're searching for jobs that don't have it).

Comment: Yes, it might have that effect - change the "acceptability" of these clauses by virtue of having the search filter. My point is that if hiring managers do not find in practice that workers won't touch roles with said clauses in the contract, they might murmur some agreement, but the contracts won't actually get changed.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are coming from employers who want to put these provisions into their contracts :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow Jobs has been discontinued.